# jQuery.pageless in Rails 3 with demo application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to integrate jQuery.pageless plugin in my application, but in vain. Can anyone provide me with some resource that shows a Rails 3 demo application that has jQuery.pageless working?

I tried looking into the example application that is provided with the plugin, which is in Rails 2.2. I tried to implement everything in a similar manner, but I get the error undefined method **'total_pages' for Array <....>**, which is the array of one of my models.

Here's the code snippets:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def pageless(total_pages, url=nil, container=nil)
    opts = {
      :totalPages => total_pages,
      :url        => url,
      :loaderMsg  => 'Loading more results'
    }

    container && opts[:container] ||= container

    javascript_tag("$('#results').pageless(#{opts.to_json});")
  end
end
```

## controller

```
def index
  @posts = Post.all

  if request.xhr?
    sleep(3) # make request a little bit slower to see loader :-)
    render :partial => "shared/post", :collection => @posts
  end
end
```

## view

```
<div id="recent-sale-item-area">
  <% if !@posts.nil? %>
    <p id="recent-posts"> recent posts </p>
    <div id="recent-sale-item-list">
      <%= render :partial => "shared/post", :collection => @posts %>
    </div>
    <%= will_paginate(@posts) %>
     <%= pageless(@posts.total_pages, posts_path) %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Github page for jQuery.pageless has what you want:

https://github.com/jney/jquery.pageless

EDIT:

Your error is because Rails 3 no longer has pagination built-in. You will need to download the [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate) or some other pagination gem, or roll your own.

Comment: Yes I did this first, that's where I downloaded the plugin from . I have changed the question a bit, please see. Thanks.

Comment: I have the will_paginate gem installed as well

Comment: Have you added `self.per_page = ` in your `Post` model as described in the `will_paginate` docs?